# I need help you with a problem of conditional probability joint continuous

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, uniform-continuity

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=x+y,    0\le x\le 1, 0\le y\le 1$

$P(X>\frac{1}{5}|Y=y)$?

My solution

$f(x|y)=\frac{x+y}{x+\frac{1}{2}}$

$P(X>\frac{1}{5}|Y=y)=$

$\int _{\frac{1}{5}}^1\:\frac{x+y^2}{x+\frac{1}{2}}dx$

My procedure is correct?

Comment: No, because you didn't use $\frac15$.

Comment: The denominator should be $y + 1/2$. $f(x|y) = \frac{x+y}{\int_{0}^1 (x+y) dx} = \frac{x+y}{y+1/2}$. Then integrate with limits $1/5 \lt x \lt 1$

Answer (score 1):

It's almost correct. The last step should use the number $\frac15$:

$f(x|y) = \frac{f(x,y) }{f(y)}= \frac{f(x,y) }{\int_{0}^1 f(x,y)dx} = \frac{x+y}{y+\frac{1}{2}}$

$P(X>\frac{1}{5}|Y=y)=\int_{\frac15}^1\:\frac{x+y^2}{y+\frac{1}{2}}dx$.

Comment: Thanks,It was a mistake.

Comment: $f_Y(y)$ should not be a function of $x$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, I didn't notice, thank you